# Oracle VirtualBox that has Mac doesnt detect my WD MyPassport HDD 2TB

Tags: mac, virtualbox, external-hard-drive

I am trying to repair WD MyPassport 2TB HDD to be used in Os X, but I don't have Mac computer so I just use a virtualbox and put mac os X there. I already format the HDD using Paragon NTFS-HFS Converter, and to test if it is working I use HFSExplorer for windows.

Unfortunately it is still not detectable on virtualbox that has mac os x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VirtualBox, you have to go to devices in the menu, then enable the USB device from the Devices menu.  Image of location in Windows 7:

[image: screen image]

Comment: Can you clarify which menu?

Comment: Take a look at this picture. http://bit.ly/1CN0sUc , it shows you exactly where it is. you have to be running Windows 7 though.

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234 I don't have a lot of reputation yet.